# Erro no Programa Visualg "sintaxe incorreta"

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Esse exercício é da faculdade, estou tentando fazer pelo `VisualG` mas sempre da essa "sintaxe de erro", o que eu fiz.
Tentei outras de outras formas mas achei essa mais fácil para compreender.

Não quero a resposta quero descobrir onde estou errando para tentar corrigir ou se tem outra forma para fazer.

```
algoritmo "valores beneficios"

var

salario, aumento, novo_sal :real

cargo :logico

   Tecnico1,  programador2, advogado3, doutor4, farmaceutico5  :caractere

INICIO

//codigo abaixo com seus respectivos valores


      ESCREVAl ("Digite o cargo do funcionário 1, 2, 3, 4 ou 5")
      LEIA (cargo)
      ESCREVAl ("Digite o valor do salario")
      LEIA (salario)

      aumento <— salario * 50 / 100
      ESCREVAl ("O valor do aumento é: ", aumento)
      novo_sal <— salario + aumento
      ESCREVAl ("O novo salario é: ", novo_sal)
      FIM

      SENÃO SE (cargo = 2)
```

eu não copiei todo o meu código porque o erro já se apresenta no começo

enunciado que estou tentando descobrir

Faça um programa que receba o código correspondente ao cargo de um funcionário e seu salário atual e mostre o cargo, o valor do aumento e seu novo salário.

Caso o usuário digite código 2 e o salário igual a R$ 1550,00. Qual será o resultado final do algoritmo?

```
ALGORITMO     SOLUÇÃO:
ALGORITMO

DECLARE salario, aumento, novo_sal, cargo NUMÉRICO
ESCREVA “Digite o cargo do funcionário (1, 2, 3, 4 ou 5).
LEIA cargo
ESCREVA “Digite o valor do salario: “
LEIA salario

SE (cargo = 1)
ENTÃO INÍCIO

ESCREVA “O cargo é Escriturário”
aumento <— salario * 50 / 100
ESCREVA “O valor do aumento é: “, aumento // 
novo_sal <— salario + aumento
ESCREVA “O novo salario é: “, novo_sal
FIM

SENÃO SE (cargo = 2)
ENTÃO INÍCIO
ESCREVA “O cargo é Secretário”
aumento <— salario * 35 / 100
ESCREVA “O valor do aumento é: “, aumento
novo_sal <— salario + aumento
ESCREVA “O novo salario é: “, novo_sal
FIM

SENÃO SE (cargo = 3)
ENTÃO INÍCIO

ESCREVA “O cargo é Caixa”
aumento <— salario * 20 / 100
ESCREVA “O valor do aumento é: “, aumento
novo_sal <— salario + aumento
ESCREVA “O novo salario é: “, novo_sal

FIM
SENÃO SE (cargo = 4)
ENTÃO INÍCIO

ESCREVA “O cargo é Gerente”
aumento <— salario * 10 / 100
ESCREVA “O valor do aumento é: “,
aumento
novo_sal <— salario + aumento
ESCREVA “O novo salario é: “, novo_sal

FIM
SENÃO SE (cargo = 5)
ENTÃO INÍCIO

ESCREVA “O cargo é Diretor”
aumento <— salario * 0 / 100
ESCREVA “O valor do aumento é: “, aumento
novo_sal <— salario + aumento
ESCREVA “O novo salario é: “, novo_sal

FIM
SENÃO ESCREVA “Cargo Inexistente!”

FIM_ALGORITMO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia! Faça isso...
Declare uma nova variável chamada salarioNovo, como tipo real; e Depois faça:

```
salarioNovo <-(salario * 50 )
  aumento <- salarioNovo / 100
  ESCREVAl ("O valor do aumento é: ", aumento)

  novo_sal <- salarioNovo + aumento
  ESCREVAl ("O novo salario é: ", novo_sal)
```

Procure comentar seu código antes de posta-lo ficará mais fácil de encontrar o erro.